# Can a potential box be a trap for Bose-Einstein Condensate? Without a potential box, can we quantize energy level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, potential, bose-einstein-condensate, bosons

I am trying to study why are traps required for Bose Einstein condensate, and what are the conditions for a trap to sustain a BEC? Equivalently, Without energy level how to define BEC?
Any comments are appreciated.